# Where does the MVC3 default template store user-account information?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Can you tell me where the asp.net mvc3 default template stores the login information when I register a new account? It is running local in debug mode.

Without having installed SQLExpress, the register function did not work at all. Since I have installed it, I can use the register/login function, but I can't find the table in SQLExpress where this kind of data is stored. There are master, model, msdb and tempdb in SQLExpress which are system databases.

Can you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the **web.config.**

```
<membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

So the plugged in membership provider is **SqlMembershipProvider**, using a connection string called *ApplicationServices*:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

So if you look in `App_Data` in your project (file system), you'll see a file called *aspnetdb.mdf*, which is where your users are being stored.

[Here's some more info on SQL Server Express.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247257.aspx)